# Передать ссылку на значение из главной сущности в собственные сущности в EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Имеется класс `Court` у которого есть вложенные классы / собственные сущности `CourtName` и `Address1`. Есть перечисление RussianRegionEnum, которое хранится в "главной" сущности. Я хотел бы передать значение этого класса по ссылке в собственные сущности `CourtName` и `Address1`, как это сделать?

```
public class Court
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //...
    public RussianRegionEnum RussianRegion { get; set; }
    public CourtName Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address1 { get; set; }

}

[Owned]
public class CourtName
{
    //...
    public RussianRegionEnum RussianRegion { get; set; }
}

[Owned]
public class Address
{
    public RussianRegionEnum RussianRegion { get; set; }
}
```

Пробовал передать значение через конструктор класса `Court` но к моменту запуска конструктора этого класса, вложенные объекты `Name` и `Address1` еще не инициализированы. Насколько я понимаю проблему можно как-то решить через внешние ключи, но я не нашел решения для собственных сущностей, которые внешних ключей не имеют.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, моя проблема решается с помощью [вычисляемых значений](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations) (computed values). Это столбцы, значение которых вычисляется на уровне базы данных исходя из констант и данных взятых из иных столбцов. В данном случае столбец Name_RussianRegion необходимо сделать вычисляемым и заставить его возвращать значение колонки RussianRegion т.е. свойство типа-владельца.
Сделать это проще всего добавив запись в OnConfiguring обработчик событий следующим образом:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Court>(court =>
        {
            court.OwnsOne(a => a.Name, reg =>
            {
                reg.Property(b => b.RussianRegion).HasComputedColumnSql("RussianRegion", stored: true);
            });
        });         
    }
```

Метод `HasComputedColumnSql` в данном случае имеет 2 параметра: первый это SQL выражение в текстовом виде, которое в данном случае просто является названием колонки значение которой возвращается. Параметр `stored: true` означает, что вычисленное значение хранится в базе данных, а не вычисляется при каждом обращении к БД.